# How to replace spaces (and special characters) in rsync transfer?

Tags: rsync

I use rsync for copying certain files to a folder (the directories are intentionally left out) which is synced to other devices with Syncthing:

```
find /mnt/media/ -name "*.epub" > /home/user/.logs/rsync/epub-paths.txt && \
rsync --archive --files-from=/home/user/.logs/rsync/epub-paths.txt  \
--no-relative / /home/user/Documents/ebooks/
```

None of the files are created by me, the filenames often contain spaces and characters which are problematic in the shell. Sadly **I can't easily rename everything on the mounted source drive**.

I planned using [detox](https://github.com/dharple/detox) to recursively process the destination ebook directory, but the program doesn't replace existing files — which in this case are all identical. Unfortunately, even if I all duplicates are removed, rsync still transfers gigabytes of data in vain each time the script is run (currently daily). Using [jdupes](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes) or similar to remove the duplicate files afterwards isn't an actual solution.

---

In short: don't modify any local data, rewrite the filenames (and folders, if I had any) in the rsync transfer before being written on the destination.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use NULL-terminated arguments:

```
find /mnt/media/ -name '*.epub' -print0 |
    rsync -as --files-from=- --from0 --no-relative / /home/user/Documents/ebooks
```

Or if your `find` is POSIX and doesn't have the `-print0` option, try this slightly less comprehensive solution:

```
find /mnt/media/ -name '*.epub' |
    rsync -as --files-from=- --no-relative / /home/user/Documents/ebooks
```

Comment: Both solutions appear to copy filenames with spaces, I tested by creating a file with `$ touch /tmp/'book title .epub'` — rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31

Comment: Are the newlines and four spaces preceding `rsync` in the answer intentional?

Comment: They are intentional but not necessary, @user598527. I use this as a visual indicator that it's a continuation line (and you can enter either pair of lines directly "as is" in any `sh`-style shell). Since you can use the first suggestion, take it in preference to the second; it will work will all possible filenames whereas the second can only work with a (large) subset of them